# How to delete a filtered column in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read a DataFrame from a CSV file and filter a subset of a column by asset class as follows:

```
df[df['Asset Class']=='Bonds']
```

How do I delete this filtered column from the original dataframe, df, and respective rows. Very new to python so bear with me on this one. I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np 
Bonds = df[df['Asset Class']=='Bonds']
np.delete(df,Bonds)
```

But comes back with an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter by the opposite of the condition:

```
df[df['Asset Class'] != 'Bonds']
```

**Reproducible Example**

```
df = DataFrame({'Asset Class': ['Bonds', 'Stocks']})
df

  Asset Class
0       Bonds
1      Stocks

df = df[df['Asset Class'] != 'Bonds']

print df
  Asset Class
1      Stocks
```